IFFT of signum in Fourier domain
The continuous Fourier transform of the signum function ($\text{sgn}(x)$) is $\frac{1}{i\pi \xi}$. If I simulate this function in MATLAB and perform an IFFT (a discrete, time limited Fourier transform), I don't quite get the signum function:
N=1000 % number of sampling points
dF=1   % frq resolution
x=((0:N-1)-ceil( (N-1)/2 ))*dF
y=1./(1i*pi*x)
y(isnan(y))=0
Y=fftshift(ifft(ifftshift(y)))

My IFFT output looks like a signum at x=0, but ramps towards 0 with $|x|$ instead of staying at -1 and +1---appearing like a signum function windowed with a triangle function:

I understand that this has to do with the differences between discrete and continuous transforms.  Can somebody provide me with a more rigorous explanation as to what is going on here for this particular function? Why this particular shape?  Are there other windows or sampling methods that I can apply in order to get something that more closely resembles a signum?

I think you are mixing up continuous and discrete Fourier transforms.  There are 4 different Fourier Transforms, which specifically are you referring too

You should add your code to your question, because we can't know what you did. How did you "simulate this function in MATLAB and perform an IFFT"? How did you deal with the singularity at DC? Are you trying to approximately compute the continuous-time inverse Fourier transform by sampling and truncation?

@Hilmar, no. Its a question about the differences between the two transforms for a specific function.  I updated the language to be a bit more clear

@MattL. Updated with code.  Yes, I am trying to approximate the continuous-time IFT by sampling and trunctation.

And what does the forward FFT of a sampled signum function look like?

@AndyWalls, it looks like an oscillation between $\frac{1}{i\pi\ \xi}$ and 0 with a period of 2x the time duration

First of all, note that sampling and truncating the continuous-time Fourier transform (CTFT) and using the IDFT is equivalent to sampling the truncated Fourier series of the continuous time domain function.
Another way to see it is that using the IDFT for approximating the inverse CTFT is equivalent to approximating the inversion integral of the CTFT by a finite Riemann sum.
What you got by setting the DC value of the Fourier transform to zero is simply the (sampled) Fourier series of a sawtooth wave. And that's exactly what you see in your figure.
The right way to do it is to sample the Fourier transform of the sign function at $\pm\Delta f$, $\pm 3\Delta f$, $\pm 5\Delta f$, etc. In this way you avoid the singularity and you don't have to make up some value for it. This leads to an expression which is identical to the Fourier series of a square wave, which is equivalent to a periodized sign function. Note that in this case only the Fourier coefficients with odd indices are non-zero.
Below is a simple Octave/Matlab code to show that the IDFT can indeed be used to approximate a sign function in the time domain. Of course, this is only possible over a certain interval, because by definition, the IDFT results in a periodic function.

N = 2000;   % fft length
X = zeros( N, 1 );
X( 2:2:N ) = ( 4 / pi ) * ( 1 ./ ( 1:2:N )' );
x = imag( N * ifft( X ) );
plot( x );



Perfect! This was exactly I was looking for.

I noticed that if you also set the the real odd coefficents (2:2:N) to -1/N (or real even coefficents to 1/N), you can get rid of the leftmost edge shown in your plot.

That's a very reasonable answer, but what bothers me about it is that it implies that the signum function and a square wave are the same thing, which they really aren't. In terms of their DFT they might be (given a certain set of assumptions) but to me that's just an indicator that the DFT is the wrong tool for the analysis. Sure, you can apply it and get a result, but is that result useful or meaningful?

@hilmar: Good point. However, whenever you sample in one domain you get periodization in the other domain. So we always must choose an interval in which our approximation is valid. We must be happy with the result inside some interval, and forget about the rest. The same thing is done when approximating a (non-periodic) function in some interval by a Fourier series. It all depends on the application if this is useful or not. Note that approximating an integral by a (finite) Riemann sum is the same thing. It might be appropriate in certain applications, but not in others.


However, if I simulate this function in MATLAB and perform an IFFT

Because the IFFT implements the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) and not the continuous Fourier Transform (CFT). You are using the wrong transform.
The DFT is not really suited to analyze a the signum function.

The signum function is not bandlimited and hence it can not be sampled without aliasing
It follows directly from the definition of the DFT that the signals must be periodic in both domains. That's a direct consequence of the sampling theorem: What is discrete in one domain must be periodic in the other.

So the DFT is the wrong tool here: the signum function is not bandlimited and its not periodic and can't be approximated by something period.
In some cases the DFT is a reasonable way to estimate the CFT but in other it's really not. The signum function is such a case.

I agree that this is true, but I would still like to know what is mathematically causing the difference.

It is indeed possible to use the IDFT here, it's just a matter of how the sampling is done and how to deal with the singularity at DC. I'll write up an answer.

@Davey what is mathematically causing the difference is that the signum extends to infinity in both directions, and the DFT is periodic.  To see this, get rid of the sampling: find the Fourier series of a continuous-time sawtooth wave like the one you have -- you'll find that the coefficients go as $\frac 1 n$, just as your input coefficients to your IDFT do.
